# Rewrite for missing url part

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a site, and I have a staging copy of the site.
In the IIS of staging site i have write a rule to  add /site-staging/ when missing in the url, this is the web.config rule:

```
<rule name="add /site-staging/ when missing">
     <match url="testsite.it\/(?!site-staging)" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="testsite.it/site-staging/" />
</rule>
```

I need to transform `testsite.it/helloword` in `testsite.it/site-staging/helloword`

Anyone can help me? I'm going crazy :(

Comment: You can get started from Mistake 1 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you trying to rewrite from`testsite.it/helloword` to `testsite.it/site-staging/helloword`? Or other needs?

Comment: @samwu, yes, and all other pages

testsite.it/helloword -> testsite.it/site-staging/helloword
testsite.it/hello -> testsite.it/site-staging/hello
testsite.it/byebye -> testsite.it/site-staging/byebye

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="testsite.it/site-staging/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: look that `testsite.it/site-staging/helloword` have no change, remain `testsite.it/site-staging/helloword`

Comment: your example match all url, i make some example:    
  
`testsite.it/helloword` -> `testsite.it/site-staging/helloword`          
`testsite.it/site-staging/helloword` -> `testsite.it/site-staging/helloword`           
`testsite.it/somepath/helloword` -> `testsite.it/site-staging/somepath/helloword`